# How to know which event was raised

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

For example, consider the following class:

```
public class Test
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> BeforeLayoutRendering;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> BeforeItemRendering;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> AfterLayoutRendering;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> AfterItemRendering;
}

public class Monitor
{
    public Monitor(Test objBeingMonitored)
    {
        objBeingMonitored.BeforeLayoutRendering += Before;
        objBeingMonitored.BeforeItemRendering += Before;
        objBeingMonitored.AfterLayoutRendering += After;
        objBeingMonitored.AfterItemRendering += After;
    }

    public void Before(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Which event was raised?
    }

    public void After(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Which event was raised?
    }
}
```

If I use the same handler for multiple events, how can I know which event was raised? I know I can change my TEventArgs class used in EventHandler, I'm just wondering if the framework has anything built-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to know:

```
public class Monitor
{
    internal enum eEvent: byte { Layout, Item }

    public Monitor( Test objBeingMonitored )
    {
        objBeingMonitored.BeforeLayoutRendering += ( s, e ) => Before( eEvent.Layout, s, e );
        objBeingMonitored.BeforeItemRendering += ( s, e ) => Before( eEvent.Item, s, e );
        objBeingMonitored.AfterLayoutRendering += ( s, e ) => After( eEvent.Layout, s, e );
        objBeingMonitored.AfterItemRendering += ( s, e ) => After( eEvent.Item, s, e );
    }

    internal void Before( eEvent evt, object sender, EventArgs e ) { }
    internal void After( eEvent evt, object sender, EventArgs e ) { }
}
```